# CSS fixed grid (offsetting on scaling)

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I am trying to implement a fixed size grid over a HTML5 canvas. I searched for answers with little luck before posting.

A grid is drawn over a canvas with an 'inner' grid. Upon scaling/scrolling in odd ratios (1.1, 1.3, 1.6 etc..) the thicker lines are offset by a number of points. (I'm working in pt not px currently)

```
//toFixed(9)
var pageWidth = Math.round( Units.toPoint( $('.canvas').width() ) );

var gridSize1 = ( pageWidth / 6 ); //6 grids wide
var gridSize2 = ( gridSize1 / 4 ); //4x4 inner grid
```

My code just generates the css like below using the two variables.

At 100% (1) zoom the canvas is 793px / 594pt;

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, black 2pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, black 2pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, black 1pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, black 1pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1pt),rgb(233, 233, 233);
background-size: 99.16666666666667pt 99.16666666666667pt, 99.16666666666667pt 99.16666666666667pt, 24.791666666666668pt 24.791666666666668pt, 24.791666666666668pt 24.791666666666668pt;
```

[image: 100%]

At 130% zoom (1.3) the canvas is 1031px / 773pt;

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, black 2pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, black 2pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, black 1pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, black 1pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1pt),rgb(233, 233, 233);
background-size: 128.83333333333334pt 128.83333333333334pt, 128.83333333333334pt 128.83333333333334pt, 32.208333333333336pt 32.208333333333336pt, 32.208333333333336pt 32.208333333333336pt;
```

[image: 130%]

At 200% zoom (2) the canvas is 1586px / 1189pt;

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, black 2pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, black 2pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, black 1pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1pt),-webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, black 1pt, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1pt),rgb(233, 233, 233);
background-size: 198.33333333333334pt 198.33333333333334pt, 198.33333333333334pt 198.33333333333334pt, 49.583333333333336pt 49.583333333333336pt, 49.583333333333336pt 49.583333333333336pt;
```

[image: 200]

Could anyone advise where I am going wrong here as I believe there is something very silly I am missing? It appears the inner grid (4x4) is moving slightly around. (sorry about the increasing size of images!)

Answer (score 0):

Forget this!

I just changed the whole implementation to use canvas drawing rather than CSS gradients.